# How to convert a free monad into a functor?

Tags: haskell, monads

The [Free structure](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Free_structure) page on the Haskell wiki defines a function to convert a functor instance into a free monad:

```
inj :: Functor f => f a -> Free f a
inj fa = Roll $ fmap Return fa
```

Then, say `inj [1,2,3]`, has type `(Num t) => Free [] t`. How do I define a function to return something like `inj [1,2,3]` back to `[1,2,3]`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @sclv says, there's no way to *directly* convert from the free monad of a functor back to the functor alone in the general case. Why not?

If you recall the "free structures" page you linked to, it first talks about free *monoids*, before extending the same concept to talk about *monads*. The free monoid for a type is a list; an equivalent "convert back" function in that case would be turning a free monoid, with type `[a]`, to a single element, with type `a`. This is obviously unworkable in two different ways: If the list is empty, it can't return anything; and if the list has multiple elements, it has to discard all but one.

The construction of a free monad is similar, and presents a similar problem. A free monad is defined by **functor composition**, which is just like regular function composition except on the *type constructor*. We can't write functor composition directly in Haskell, but just like `f . g` means `\x -> f (g x)`, we can nest application of the type constructor. For example, composing `Maybe` with itself gives a type like `Maybe (Maybe a)`.

So, in other words, where a plain functor describes a parameterized structure of some sort, the free monad of that functor describes that structure nested within itself to arbitrary depth.

So if we look at `Free [] Int`, it could be a single `Int`, a list of `Int`s, a list of lists of `Ints`, and so on.

So, just like **we can only turn a free monoid (list) directly into a single item if the list is exactly one item long**, we can only convert a free monad directly to the underlying functor **if the nesting is exactly one layer deep**.

---

If you're interested in general ways to take things back out of a free monad, you'll need to go a bit further--some sort of recursive fold-like operation to collapse the structure.

In the specific case of the free monad for lists, there's one obvious approach--recursively flatten the structure by stripping out the `Roll` and `Return` constructors and concatenating lists as you go. It may also be enlightening to think about *why* this approach works in this case, and how it relates to the structure of lists.

Comment: Thankyou very much. I had mistakenly thought that the `inj` function was smarter than it is; so there's really no way "in", or "out". On the other hand, you do hint at a possible solution, and that makes me first think of the `Free` type's `(>>=)` definition; and then both Oleg Kiselyov's [Deep monadic join](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/typecast.html#deep-join), and Wouter Swierstra's [Data types à la carte](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~wss/Publications/DataTypesALaCarte.pdf) come to mind.

Comment: @user643722: If you enjoy this sort of thing, [Edward Kmett has implemented a lot of these sorts of concepts](https://github.com/ekmett) in Haskell and has written about them in various locations. For instance, [this](http://knol.google.com/k/catamorphisms#) might be of interest. Also related to the current topic--what does the free monad for the functor `(,) Int` look like?

Comment: @camccann: Yes, I take what I am able to from Edward's output. And thankyou for the question, but it seems it's a little beyond me for now; all I see is a soup of `Roll`s and `Return`s. Still, I'm pleased the very obvious thing I hadn't noticed before can be seen even from free monoids: given an "input" set, the binary op. of the "output" free monoid, does not operate upon elements of the input set. Another question I have is: The booleans have four monoids: (False,OR), (False,XOR), (True,AND) and (True,XNOR). Are any of them free monoids?

Comment: @user643722: A "free" monoid is essentially the simplest monoid possible for a set. Lists of elements are a generic version, so any free monoid on a set has to be isomorphic to that. For one of those to be a free monoid, you'd need to be able to convert `[Bool]` to `Bool` using the monoid definition, then back to `[Bool]` and always recover the same list you started with.

Comment: camccann: Yes, but the recursive flattening of `Roll` and `Return` you propose for `Free []` works other monads as well. This is one case where the tongue in cheek statement that "a monad is a monoid in the category of endofunctors" is actually useful. ;)

Comment: @Edward Kmett: Yes, yes, those are precisely the conclusions I was fishing for with my remark about considering *why* it works for lists. :) You're really crimping my Socratic Method style here! But I suppose that doesn't work so well on SO anyway, alas.

Comment: @camccann: Hmm...how about a hint: *is* one of them a free monoid? I thought that in the generic version I would be using `(++)`, but then you present only one `[Bool]`. Can I assume that list has one element?

Comment: @user643722: Remember, when considering the free monoid over a type, the elements of the *monoid* are lists, not individual values of that type. So for an operation on elements of a *type* to give you a free monoid *on that type*, the elements of the type need to, in some sense, contain as much information as a list of that type. It should be easy to see that this can't the case for `Bool`, or in fact any type with a finite number of values.

Comment: Wikipedia states that the monoid of natural numbers (N,+) is constructed from a single generator, and so has rank 1. Is this like a `data One = One`, and then `[One,One] ++ [One,One]` corresponds to four? Is the monoid of multiplication (N,*) also a free monoid?

Comment: @user643722: I think that's correct for adding natural numbers, yes. Probably not for multiplication, though, at least not in the obvious way--I think having a rank greater than one and being commutative is sufficient to demonstrate that, but I don't have time to work through the details right now, sorry.

Answer (score 16):

The first thing to observe is that a variation of `inj` makes `Free` into something that is almost a monad transformer.

I'll use [Control.Monad.Free](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/free/0.2.1/doc/html/Control-Monad-Free.html), from my [free](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free) package on hackage, to avoid repeating everything here. This means that `Roll` becomes `Free` and `Return` is instead named `Pure` in the code below, relative to the version on the wiki.

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Free -- from 'free'

instance MonadTrans Free where
    lift = Free . liftM Pure
```

You cannot however go in the other direction for an arbitrary `Functor`. However, if you have an instance of `Monad` on `m`, you can undo lifting by flattening `Free m` down to a single layer of the underlying monad `m`!

```
retract :: Monad f => Free f a -> f a  
retract (Pure a) = return a
retract (Free as) = as >>= retract
```

The name is chosen because this is a [retraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_(category_theory)) of `lift`. So called because

```
retract . lift = id
```

holds as shown by

```
retract (lift as) =                        -- by definition of lift
retract (Free (liftM Pure as)) =           -- by definition of retract
liftM Pure as >>= retract =                -- by definition of liftM
as >>= \a -> return (Pure a) >>= retract = -- first monad law
as >>= \a -> retract (Pure a)              -- by definition of retract
as >>= \a -> return a =                    -- eta reduction
as >>= return                              -- second monad law
as
```

so the function `retract` undoes the work of `lift`.

Since `fmap` = `liftM`, this holds for `inj` as well.

Note that `lift . retract` is *not* `id`. There simply isn't enough space to put everything in the intervening type -- the use of the monad smashes everything flat -- but `lift . retract . lift . retract = lift . retract` holds because `lift . retract . lift . retract = lift . id . retract = lift . retract`, so `lift . retract` is idempotent.

The problem with this 'lift' is that 'lift' is not a monad homomorphism, but is instead only a monad homomorphism 'up to retract', so this pushes the burden of preserving the monad transformer laws on the user of the lifted computations, so it makes sense to retain inj as a separate function name.

I'm actually going to go add `retract` to the free package right now. I needed it recently for an article I'm writing anyways.

Comment: In my experience, the opposite of lifting something is dropping it, and it's certainly expected that dropping something on the floor, such as a piece of food, and then lifting it again is different from never dropping it at all. Also, inventing terrible metaphors for category theory is surprisingly enjoyable. Anyway, +1 for being informative, and for being who I learned a lot of this stuff from myself. :)

Comment: Hah! If `drop` wasn't such an overloaded name, I'd adopt it for this. =)

Comment: I hope you write this all down in a book one day Edward!

Comment: I thought you might appreciate that. I believe you were the person I saw define the field accessor for a fixpoint `newtype Nu f` as `old`, which is even more sublime. :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why you're asking for this function, and there is in general no single function of type `Free f a -> f a`. However, there *is* an inverse to `inj` -- which is to say, there is a function of that type *if* you know that the structure is an outer Roll with one layer of Return. If there are any deeper `Roll`s, then this will fail with pattern match errors, so its sort of a silly thing to begin with. However, here you go:

```
unInj :: Functor f => Free f a -> f a
unInj (Roll x) = fmap (\(Return y) -> y) x
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right: both `inj` and `unInj` are a bit shallow.

Comment: This isn't the ideal retraction for lift, as it isn't total. See my other response.

Comment: @Edward Kmett: Sure, which I pointed out :-). It's the only retraction for inj you can get with only a Functor though, I think.